# matplotlib and seaborn print nothing but did not get any error messgae

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using matplotlib and seaborn with default setting，it's werid I could not plot anyhing out.what could it possibly be wrong？

```
LoanStats_securev1_2018Q1_unique['loan_status'].head()

0    Current
1    Current
2    Current
3    Current
4    Current
Name: loan_status, dtype: object
```

howerver,this line return nothing and no error:

```
sns.countplot(x="loan_status", data=LoanStats_securev1_2018Q1, palette="Greens_d");

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x993d455668>
```

Comment: Do you have `show()` function call anywhere in your script? And what is the graphics backend that is in use?

Comment: what happens if you execute the code without the ending `;`? `sns.countplot(x="loan_status", data=LoanStats_securev1_2018Q1, palette="Greens_d")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib in Jupyter please add following line

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: yeah I had same problem long time ago, I remember it took me some time to find, glad that I could help. If the issue is closed please don't forget to click on green tick below the answer =)